# How could I make HTML5 video change/seek faster?

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, html5-video

I have a web application, which is based on the idea that there are different recordings of the same event from multiple angles. I can watch the video and change between the different recordings on the fly. It is achieved with two video tags, I load the requested new recording to the second video tag, which is hidden, seek to the position and when it is ready to play, I hide the first one and make this second one visible (as advised in this post: [How can I seamlessly change a playing video on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530705/how-can-i-seamlessly-change-a-playing-video-on-a-website) ).

When I run this application on my local machine, it works like a charm, the changes are seamless. However, if I deploy it to a server, the changes became so slow that it becomes really disturbing. Obviously, one important factor here is the available bandwidth. But in an earlier version, I used just one video tag and loaded the new video into the same video tag, sought to the desired position there and started the video there. This early version had short interruptions but generally, the delay of changing between recordings was much shorter. With the current solution, there is no interruption, the play never stops but it takes much more time to change to the new recording. I don't understand why that happens if it changed faster with the earlier solution. Do you have any recommendations, how I could optimize it? This is the main logic that changes the track:

```
        otherVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
            otherVideo.currentTime = video.currentTime
            otherVideo.play().then(() => {
                setActiveVideoRef(activeVideoRef == 1 ? 2 : 1);
                handleSizeChanges();

                setTimeout(() => {
                    video.pause()
                }, 700);
            })
        }, {once: true})
        otherVideo.setAttribute('src', url);
```

Maybe loading the track into the invisible video tag happens with lower priority in the browsers JavaScript engine? What could be the source of the difference?

The video tracks are the same and the format is: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `change to the new recording` what part of the code is doing that?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it needs some more clarification. It is the last line in my quoted code. Before that, it is set up that once the video is loaded, it is sought to the desired position, started and when it is started, the active video is changed, making it visible and hiding the other. Finally, with some delay, the other (now invisible) video is stopped.